# $X$ ~ $N(u, \sigma^2)$. Find $E(X)$

Tags: probability, expectation

$X$ ~ $N(u, \sigma^2)$. Find $E(X)$

We know that $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-u}{\sigma} \right)^2}$

Also,

$Z = \frac{X-u}{\sigma}$ ~ $N(0, 1)$, so $f_Z(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}z^2}$

$E(Z) = E\left[\frac{X}{\sigma} - \frac{u}{\sigma} \right] = \frac{1}{\sigma}E(X) + \frac{u}{\sigma}E(1) = E(X) = u$

Therefore $E(X) = u$ for $X$ ~ $N(u, \sigma^2)$

I don't get it. The part where "$\frac{1}{\sigma}E(X) + \frac{u}{\sigma}E(1) = E(X) = u$"

I'm aware that $X$ ~ $N(0, 1)$, $E(X) = 0$.

Comment: The Line $E(Z)=E[\frac{X}{\sigma}-\frac{u}{\sigma}]$ is wrong.  The rest of the line should be $\frac{1}{\sigma}E(X)-\frac{u}{\sigma}=0$.

Comment: Why not perform the integration $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf_X(x)\,dx$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a very big mistake. First of all, the expectation operator is linear, therefore
$$E(Z) = \frac{1}{\sigma}E(X) - \frac{\mu}{\sigma}E(1) = \frac{\mu}{\sigma}-\frac{\mu}{\sigma} =0 $$

Second of all, the title's content is different from what you are asking. So from hereon, I will address the question in the title:
$$E(X) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x f_X(x)$$
where 
$$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(x-\mu)^2}$$
So
$$E(X) = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(x-\mu)^2} \ dx$$
Take a change of variable $t = x-\mu$ so $dt = dx$ and then
$$E(X) = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} (t+\mu) e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}t^2} \ dt = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} t e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}t^2} \ dt+\mu  \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}  \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}t^2} \ dt$$
So the first integral evaluates to zero because it is an odd function. The second integral is the integration of the Normal PDF hence it evaluates to 1. Finally
$$E(X) = 0 + \mu(1) = \mu$$